# Writing complete XML File with Classic ASP

Tags: xml, asp-classic

i get an XML File from one Webservice and just need to print the whole XML File as recieved with Classic ASP.

XML File reading:

```
strURL = "http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=" & weather & "&hl=" & hl

set xmlDoc = createObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", true
bLoaded = xmlDoc.load(strURL)
```

Is there an easy way to print out the whole XML File like Response.Write xmlDoc.xml or an other way?

Answer (score 5):

A lesser know alterative to Response.Write is:

```
 Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
 Response.CharSet = "UTF-8"
 xmlDoc.save Response
```

This causes the xmlDoc write the xml directly to the response stream.  This slightly more efficient than generating a Unicode string returned by the `xml` property only to re-encode it into the reponse stream with `Response.Write`.

Comment: It worked for me.. I could find the error.. thx u @AnthonyWJones

Answer (score 2):

`bLoaded.xml` will contain the loaded XML.

See the documentation for [`MSXML2.DOMDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So, yes:

```
Response.Write bLoaded.xml
```

Will output the XML. You may want to HTML encode it first and possibly pretty print it first.